# Pyspark equivalent for groupby and aggregation

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe and i am trying to perform groupby and aggregation on that.

I am performing the following operations in Pandas and its working fine:

```
new_df = new_df.groupBy('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'H', 'K', 'L', 'Cost1','Cost2','Cost3','Cost4','Cost5')

new_df = new_df.agg({'Cost1':sum, 'Cost2':sum, 'Cost3':sum,'Cost4':sum, 'Cost5':sum})
```

But i am unable to perform the same operations in Pyspark using the below syntax:

```
new_df = new_df.groupBy('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'H', 'K', 'L', 'Cost1','Cost2','Cost3','Cost4','Cost5').agg(F.sum(ost1','Cost2','Cost3','Cost4','Cost5'))
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'groupBy'
```

Comment: " i am unable to perform" what do you mean ? and you should remove the collect

Comment: @maximeG : thanks, i updated the error i am getting

Comment: You should show a [mcve] of how new_df gets created

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here `(ost1',`. you forgot `'C`. And the error relates to another problem in your code. You probably call groupBy() twice like this: `groupBy("A").groupBy("B")`. You can not do this. You should call one of aggregation function from GrouppedData object after groupBy(). I think, you need these code

```
new_df =  df.groupBy("A", "B").sum("Cost1", "Cost2")
new_df.show()
```